# What's the best personal email address if the domain is already my first name?

Tags: email, names

Pretend my name is John; I own the domain name `john.me`. I will be using this domain for a portfolio site, to host small projects, etc.

When setting up the email server I thought through some ideas for my email address and, honestly, none seemed too appealing:

- `admin@john.me` seems like it's for inquires relating to the website itself`
- `contact@john.me` seems weird and not used often
- `john@john.me` seems overly redundant, strikes me as odd
- `me@john.me` seems too playful

Am I better off using a known provider such as `@gmail.com` or `@yahoo.com`?

What email address should I use which is consistent, less likely to be forgotten, and the least confusing for clients, employers, and anyone emailing me?

Answer (score 2):

Besides agreeing with the options you provided above, there're also possibilities like below,

> info@john.me,
>
> inquiries@john.me,
>
> mail@john.me

which I use the last one, but with my surname additionally next to my name like **mail@johndoe.me**

Answer (score 2):

There are several fun ideas you could explore like:

**- chat@john.me
 - work@john.me
 - hey@john.me**

e.t.c

Answer (score 1):

I own a domain that's my full name (e.g. firstnamelastname.com). My email address is firstname@firstnamelastname.com. I've found it easy to give it to people in person or over the phone (as opposed to some weird name you may have to pick if you use Gmail etc., for example).

The only times people found it weird was because it was my own domain (some people didn't know that was possible, thinking you could only get addresses from your ISP or the likes of Gmail, Hotmail and Yahoo).

I find it's more professional to have an email with your domain name (when you have one, that is), but that's rather subjective.